# Repackaging .pkg files without installing/unpacking

Tags: macos, install, pkg

Recently I was tasked with finding out a way to prepare OS X applications for automatic distribution to multiple machines.

Most applications require some tampering with their preferences before deploying. I have done it for Windows machines before, and usually I could just replace the preference files/registry entries right inside the .msi installer, using tools like Orca, Wise Package Studio and so on.

I am new to macs, but when I try to look for something similar for OS X, all I find is software to make packages from scratch (PackageMaker, Iceberg, etc.), but nothing for editing already created .pkg files.

So here is the question: is there a way to easily edit the content of .pkg file (replace some files, add a script, etc.), without having to install/unpackage it and then package the configured stuff back?

Comment: Do You have flat packages or bundles?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, it is not specified, so I have to assume we can have both.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, "flat" meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier Apple introduced new `pkg` format "Flat Packade Format" on OS X 10.5 - more info http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Ivanhoe/FLAT.html
And a difference between the flat and bundled is that bundled package can be opened in Finder with RightClick ->  "Show Package Content".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Flat Package Editor** from Apple.

1. Go to Apple's Developer downloads site and download the [Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/auxiliary_tools_for_xcode__late_july_2012/xcode44auxtools6938114a.dmg).
2. Once downloaded, open the DMG.
3. Find PackageMaker.app and open the package contents, then navigate to Contents/Resources.
4. Copy Flat Package Editor.app to /Applications or elsewhere then open it.

From this app you can open a .pkg and edit the contents by dragging files out, editing them and dragging them back in, then saving the package.

---

Packages can be resigned using the button on the title bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this tool looks useful. Doesn't work with bundles, but I guess it's an outdated format and I probably won't have to deal with it too much. Some sources claim it is quite buggy, though.

Comment: I was able to find this download by searching apple's developer downloads. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndjs39zalj3t9oy/Screenshot%202018-01-01%2002.41.49.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any Apple recommended tools to edit existing package, `pkg` or `mpkg`, files. Most packages are signed and thus any changes will invalidate their signature; although resigning is simple enough using `pkgbuild` and an [appropriate installer certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/how-to-create-an-apple-installer-package-signing-certificate).

### Wrapping Up Existing Packages

Consider creating a wrapper multi-package that adjusts any required files after installation. With this approach you can bundle up existing packages and then run post-install/update scripts as required.

### pkgbuild

There is little documentation about crafting packages as Apple traditionally relied on the graphical tool PackageMaker. Since Mac OS X 10.8, the PackageMaker tool has been replaced by the command line tools [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html) and [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html).

The tool you will want to investigate is `pkgbuild`. This tool eases the creation of packages containing multiple packages and scripts. [About Distribution Definition Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html) talks about the internal file format.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider wrapping packages instead of editing them, so I will look into it if Flat Package Editor won't be able to help me.